# Singleton , Critical section

Tags: c#, java, design-patterns

What should one prefer in case of Singleton Design Pattern.

```
1)make whole getInstance() method synchronized 
OR
2)make only critical section synchronized.
```

what should be one's approach and why?

Comment: Why `getInstance` should be synchronized at all?

Comment: Synchronize it only on initialization. if it's already initialized just return the instance.

Comment: Prefer not to have a singleton in the first place, then prefer to let someone else create it for you, e.g. your friendly dependency injection container, and finally if you really really absolutely need to 1.

Comment: pls, give reason for your choice.

Comment: @iccthedral actually the nullcheck and initialization must be in the same synchronized block. That is the trick of synchronization in singleton pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, try to consider whether or not you *need* lazy instantiation. If not, there's no synchronization involved since your `INSTANCE` will be initialized at class loading time.

If you do need to lazily initialize your instance, then do *not* make `getInstance` synchronized, as this would cause all your threads to wait for each other for no reason once the instance is initialized.

If you'll use a synchronized block inside, you need to double-check for null (outside and inside the synchronized block) to make sure you end up with only one instance; also, you need your instance to be `volatile`.

The best-practice approach is to have a private nested class `SingletonHolder` that initializes the instance of your singleton at load time (but is only loaded when `getInstance()` of the container class is called).

However, if you don't need lazy instantiation, the best-practice is to use an enum with one constant.

---

Long story short, I think you'll find it all here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: Double checked locking is not a solution, see : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dcl/index.html . Initalization at class loading time is good for "util" singleton. It might be hard if it needs DB connection or something like that. Try to unit-test code that uses such singletons.

Comment: @Piotr: From that article: "Editor's note: This article refers to the Java Memory Model before it was revised for Java 5.0; statements about memory ordering may no longer be correct." The new memory model in Java 5.0 fixes the issues and `volatile` is reliable now.

Comment: Well that's great. I overlooked that.

Answer (score 3):

Given that [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) is often regarded as an anti-pattern, I would question why you want it at all.

> This pattern makes unit testing far more difficult,[6] as it
>   introduces global state into an application. It should also be noted
>   that this pattern reduces the potential for parallelism within a
>   program, because access to the singleton in a multi-threaded context
>   must be serialised, e.g., by locking. Advocates of dependency
>   injection would regard this as an anti-pattern, mainly due to its use
>   of private and static methods

If at all possible I would try to use [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to resolve the above issues.

Comment: anti-patterns, I spit on them

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use an `enum` because it much simpler and is still thread safe and lazy loaded.

```
enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

I wouldn't make it more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

Read `Item 3` from `Effective java` `enforce singleton with property with private constructed or an enum type`

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is not to use singleton at all.
If you reeealy need to use singleton in multi-threaded envoronment make whole `getInstance` synchronized or use static field initalized at once (even worse for unit testing).

Read http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dcl/index.html